# I am trying to view and download a file that I have uploaded using django web application. The web does not open when clicking on view or download

Tags: html, django, server

Here is my HTML home.html template.

```
<a href="{{MEDIA_URL}}/{{post.file_field.url}}" class="btn btn-warning" target="_blank">View</a>
                
<a href="{{MEDIA_URL}}/{{post.file_field.url}}" class="btn btn-info mx-4" download>Download</a>
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media/'
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('photoapp.urls')),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Show us the view code.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.